# Does .NET have thread safe generic classes?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have implemented my own [RingBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185074/net-terminating-threads-in-an-orderly-fashion), but I'm surprised to see that .NET does not have one.  Or even a simply thread safe queue, list or collection?

Why doesn't .NET contain thread safe classes?  Are they planned for the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread safety of general purpose collection classes is of dubious value - more often than not, you don't really need individual operations on them (such as `Add` or the indexer) to be thread-safe, but you rather need group of operations to be thread-safe. For example, if one thread inserts new items into the collection, while another accesses items in a loop via indexer, it won't matter if both of those methods on the collection will lock it - the code is still broken. That said, some old non-generic collection classes in `System.Collections`, such as `Hashtable`, are thread-safe.

Now thread-safe `Queue` and `Stack` classes are actually useful (the limitations of their protocol make them suitable for general concurrent access), so their omission isn't really by design, but more of an oversight (or, more likely, constrained resources). However, you'll see `ConcurrentQueue` and `ConcurrentStack` in .NET 4.0

Comment: Ahh, yes.  SyncRoot I believe.

Answer (score 1):

They will be present in .NET 4.0, I believe in the System.Threading.Collections namespace (or that's the namespace they were in in the last CTP I looked at).

Answer (score 0):

The .NET 4.0 Framework introduces several thread-safe collections in the System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace:

ConcurrentBag
      Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects.

ConcurrentDictionary
    Represents a thread-safe collection of key-value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

ConcurrentQueue
    Represents a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection.

ConcurrentStack
    Represents a thread-safe last in-first out (LIFO) collection.